# Compute pdf parameters given a probability value

Tags: probability, integration

Suppose I have a certain distribution i do not know the parameters. As an example, consider a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Given $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, i know the value of $P(a \leq X \leq b) = k$, with $a,b \in ]-\infty,\infty[, a < b$. Is there a way to find the values of mean and variance that give $k$ as result? There will be an infinite number of pairs i suppose, but how can i compute them? Inverting the integral? Similairly, fixing one of the two parameters, the solution will be unique. Is there any general way/theorem to do this (also not directly related to probability)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are given $k$, find for which $a,b \  P(a<Z<b)=k$, where $Z \sim N(0,1)$. Then, solve for $\mu, \sigma$
$$
x_1= \mu + a \sigma\\
x_2 = \mu + b \sigma
$$

Comment: I need to find mean and variance and not set it to 0 and 1. a, b and k are known

Comment: @Alex : sorry but reading the OP comment I posted an example :(

Comment: Yes, you find the mean and variance from the set of equations

Answer (score 1):

Let's have an example....

$X\sim N(\mu;\sigma^2)$

Suppose we know that

$\mathbb{P}[3<X<4]=0.9$

This means that

$\mathbb{P}[\frac{3-\mu}{\sigma}<Z<\frac{4-\mu}{\sigma}]=0.9$

Where Z is the Standard Gaussian

Thus

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{3-\mu}{\sigma}=-1.64 \\ 
\frac{4-\mu}{\sigma}=1.64
\end{cases}
$$

now you can solve the system and get the values of your parameters...

Comment: Thanks. Where does +- 1.64 cames from? This only applies to Normal distributed r.v. In general, there is there an algorithm to find the parameters of a general distribution?

Comment: @damianodamiano : $\pm 1.64$ come from the Standard Normal table..if you are not familiar with this table I suggest you to review it